# Do quadratures in quantum optics have a physical meaning?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, quantum-optics

Do [quadratures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_phase_space#Properties_of_quadratures) in [quantum optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_optics) have a physical meaning? Or are they just defined as such to satisfy the same [commutation relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) as the position and momentum operators ?